# Throw Exception in ModelListener Liferay

Tags: liferay, hook

Hello Liferay Experts,

I have a requirement where I need to stop an Admin from assigning a role, I am trying to implement this with a ModelListener.

Here is the code..

```
@Component(immediate = true, service = ModelListener.class)
public class TestUserModelListener extends BaseModelListener<User> {

    @Override
    public void onBeforeAddAssociation(Object classPK, String associationClassName, Objext accociationClassPK) throws ModelListenerException {
        // ...
        throw new ModelListenerException("User creation not allowed");
    }
}
```

When this code executes, the exception is thrown but the UI doesnt handle it correctly, the control panel Menus are not displayed and the exception message is not displayed to the user.

How to throw an exception and handle it correctly in UI and display error message to the user.

Thanks

M

Comment: Did you try to set your error messages via SessionErrors.add operation. I don't know, if you have a request object access (maybe threadlocal).

Comment: Also, You can try to [wrap/extends the MVC ActionCommand](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/overriding-mvc-commands#overriding-mvcactioncommand). I guess that you could use `mvc.command.name=/users_admin/update_user_roles` (not tested) - see [here](https://github.com/liferay/com-liferay-users-admin/blob/master/users-admin-web/src/main/java/com/liferay/users/admin/web/internal/portlet/action/UpdateUserRolesMVCActionCommand.java)

Answer (score 1):

Andre Albert already gave you the correct hints in the comments.
You should keep the ModelListener and override the ActionCommand additionally.

First, read the tutorial about [Overriding MVC Comands](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/overriding-mvc-commands). When implementing your custom Command, use [Liferay's implemenation](https://github.com/liferay/com-liferay-users-admin/blob/master/users-admin-web/src/main/java/com/liferay/users/admin/web/internal/portlet/action/UpdateUserRolesMVCActionCommand.java) as basis (don't forget to add the higher service.ranking) and replace the catch block with something like this:

```
// I took the freedom and refactored Liferay's catch block a little bit
catch (NoSuchUserException | PrincipalException e) {
    SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, e.getClass());
    actionResponse.setRenderParameter("mvcPath", "/error.jsp");
} catch (MembershipPolicyException e) {
    SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, e.getClass(), e);
    actionResponse.setRenderParameter("mvcPath", "/edit_user.jsp");
    actionResponse.setRenderParameter("screenNavigationCategoryKey", UserFormConstants.CATEGORY_KEY_GENERAL);
    actionResponse.setRenderParameter("screenNavigationEntryKey", UserFormConstants.ENTRY_KEY_ROLES);
} catch (ForbiddenRoleAssociationException e) {
    // Here you can add a SessionError
    // and set some render parameters
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
```

The `ForbiddenRoleAssociationException` does not exist yet. It's purpose is to distinguish this special case of a `ModelListenerException` from others which might not interest you. You'll have to implement it yourself. Just extend the `ModelListenerException`:

```
public class ForbiddenRoleAssociationException extends ModelListenerException {
    // here might be some constructors
}
```

Now adjust your ModelListener so that it throws your new `ForbiddenRoeAssociationException`:

```
@Component(immediate = true, service = ModelListener.class)
public class TestUserModelListener extends BaseModelListener<User> {

    @Override
    public void onBeforeAddAssociation(Object classPK, String associationClassName, Objext accociationClassPK) throws ModelListenerException {
        // ...
        throw new ForbiddenRoleAssociationException(); // or any other constructor
    }
}
```

This way you should be able to display error messages to admins (depending on your code in the catch block of the `ForbiddenRoleAssociationException`) and circumvent any other (programmatic) attempt to assign the Role as well.